# How to get valid address through @google/maps?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Node.js microservice I'm using:

```
"@google/maps": "^0.5.5"

googleMapsClient.geocode({address: '160 Market St, Paterson, NJ 07505'})
    .asPromise()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(response.json));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error: " + err);
    });
```

in response I get: `"location_type":"ROOFTOP"` and `"types":["street_address"]` that means the address is valid

If I try to validate same address but with invalid state, e.g. 'NO' it still returns `"location_type":"ROOFTOP"` and `"types":["street_address"]`. Assume because google API formats it that can be seen in the response:

```
"formatted_address":"160 Market St, Paterson, NJ 07505, USA"
```

Sometimes google API returns `"location_type":"ROOFTOP"` and `"types":["premise"]`

Sure I can filter the results by `location_type` and `types` but I really want to consider address as valid if it can be found in `@types/googlemaps AutoComplete`. This is what I'm using in UI (Angular):

```
"@types/googlemaps": "3.30.16"
const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(e.target, {
    types: ['address']
});

var place = google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

Even it's just defined as `types: ['address']` in `AutoComplete` it can be found as `"types":["street_address"]` or `"types":["premise"]` in `"@google/maps"`..
So how make Node.js returns only addresses that can be found in AutoComplete?

Comment: Maybe this can help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014733/how-to-store-lat-and-long-from-google-places-autocomplete-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) is also supported by `@google/maps` library, it could be accomplished like this:

```
//1. query predictions
googleMapsClient.placesQueryAutoComplete(
  {
    input: "160 Market St, Paterson, NJ 07505"
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
      if (response.json.predictions.length === 0) {
        console.log("Place not found");
      } else {
        var prediction = response.json.predictions[0]; //select first prediction
        //2. query place by prediction
        googleMapsClient.place(
          {
            placeid: prediction.place_id
          },
          function(err, response) {
            if (!err) {
              console.log(response.json.result); //prinat place
            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Explanation:

- `placesQueryAutoComplete` function is utilized first which returns array of query predictions based on query
- `place` function returns the place details by providing `placeId` parameter extracted from previous response